# Listar ultima sesion de los usuarios

Tags: vbscript

Tengo esta funcion que coge el ultimo usuario que iniciado sesion en un pc.

```
Function GetLastLogon

Dim LastLogonUser
Dim Count
Dim Final
Dim VFInal

LastLogonUser =objRegistry.RegRead("HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Authentication\LogonUI\LastLoggedOnUser")
Count=InStr(LastLogonUser,"\")
Final = Count + 1
VFInal=Mid(LastLogonUser,Final)
GetLastLogon = VFinal

End Function
```

Me preguntava si hay alguna manera de hacer una lista de todos los usuarios que han accedido a una sola maquina, por que la funcion solo muestra el ultimo usuario.

Lo que se me ocurrio es lo siguiente, acceder a la carpeta usuarios y mirar alli.

```
Set objFS = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objFile = objFS.GetFolder("C:\Users")
set subfolder = objFile.subFolders
For each Name in subfolder 
   Wscript.Echo(Name)
next
```

Entonces me pregunta si hay alguna otra forma de hacerlo que nos sea acceder a la carpeta users? 
Llevo toda la mañana mirando pero encontrado.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Al final lo encontrado, dejo aqui la respuesta

```
Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:\\.\root\cimv2")
Set colItems = objWMIService.ExecQuery("Select * from  Win32_NetworkLoginProfile")

For Each objItem in colItems
Wscript.Echo objItem.Name
Next
```

Con esto lista todos los usuarios de una maquina.

Comment: Si crees que la pregunta esta respondida deberías marcarlo o borrarla.
Por otro lado, eso lista aquellos usuarios actualmente logueados en la computadora ([Creo](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394221(v=vs.85).aspx)). No estoy seguro de si hay un lugar mejor, pero en el registro `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\ProfileList` el valor de `ProfileImagePath` de cada una de las subclaves tiene "Lo mismo" que encontrabas en la carpeta C:\Users.

Comment: gracias, con esto ya me soluciona mi problema, no me deja marcarla como respuesta aun, hasta mañana no la puedo marcar